# Receiving JSON error when trying to populate fields from MongoDB to HTML using Python, Ajax calls and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, mongodb

I am using Python to retrieve data from MongoDB database, this is then sent to Javascript using Ajax, the data is then used to populate fields in the HTML of a page. When running the application on local machine it works as it should do, however when running the application on the Ubuntu server I get the below error:

> VM1419:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

This is the Javascript function which produces the error:

```
function restoreData(){

$.get("restore_tab", function (tab_data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(tab_data);

    for (var i=0; i<parsed.length; i++){
        var tab_does_exist = document.getElementById(parsed[i].tab_number);
        if(tab_does_exist.innerHTML !== parsed[i].tab_name){
            createTab(parsed[i].tab_number, parsed[i].tab_name);
        }
    }
});

$.get("sender", function (data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

    for (i = 1; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var clear = tabs[i].innerHTML = "";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
        var delete_title = parsed[i].title;
        var restore = document.getElementById(parsed[i].tab);
        console.log(parsed[i].tab);

        restore.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<div id='close_container_${parsed[i].article_id}'>
    <div class='close_border' id='close_border_${parsed[i].article_id}'>
        <div class='close_bar' id='close_bar_${parsed[i].article_id}'>
            <div class='close_btn' id='close_${parsed[i].article_id}' onclick='remove(id)'>×</div>
            <div id='full_article_${parsed[i].article_id}'>
                <h1 id='article_title_${parsed[i].article_id}'>${parsed[i].title}</h1>
                <div class='tooltip'>
                    <button type='button' onclick='saveArticle(event, id)' id='save_article_${parsed[i].article_id}'class='button ripple'>Update</button>
                    <textarea cols='120' rows='3' onclick='copy('article_reference_${parsed[i].article_id}'); copiedText('copied_${parsed[i].article_id}')' readonly type='text' id='article_reference_${parsed[i].article_id}' class='ref'>${parsed[i].reference}</textarea>
                    <span id='copied_${parsed[i].article_id}' class='tooltip_text'>click to copy &#x2398</span>
                </div>             
                <div onclick='speedRead(id)' class='speed_read' id='speed_read_${parsed[i].article_id}'>Click to SpeedRead</div>
                <p class='article_text' id='article_text_${parsed[i].article_id}'>${parsed[i].body}</p>
                <a id='article_url_${parsed[i].article_id}' target='_blank' href= ${parsed[i].url}>Click to open full article</a>
                <p style='color:#546de5;font-weight:900'>Your notes: </p>
                <textarea id='article_notes_${parsed[i].article_id}' placeholder='type article notes here'>${parsed[i].notes}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`)
    }
});}
```

On the developer console this is what is being retrieved by the database causing the error:

> [{"tab": "tab_2", "article_id": "746169745", "url": "http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12870-019-1847-2&quot;, "reference": "Reference: (2019-05-30). Transcriptional regulation of MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 by MdFLP during apple self-rooted stock adventitious root gravitropism, Available at: http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12870-019-1847-2 Last Accessed: [03-06-19]", "notes": "", "title": "Transcriptional regulation of MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 by MdFLP during apple self-rooted stock adventitious root gravitropism", "body": "AbstractBackgroundThe close planting of dwarfing self-rooted rootstocks is currently a widely used method for apple production; however, self-rooted rootstocks are weak with shallow roots and poor grounding. Therefore, understanding the molecular mechanisms that establish the gravitropic set-point angles (GSAs) of the adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks is important for developing self-rooted apple rootstock cultivars with deep roots.ResultsWe report that the apple FOUR LIPS (MdFLP), an R2R3-MYB transcription factor (TF), functions in establishing the GSA of the adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks in response to gravity. Biochemical analyses demonstrate that MdFLP directly binds to the promoters of two auxin efflux carriers, MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 , that are involved in auxin transport, activates their transcriptional expression, and thereby promotes the development of adventitious roots in self-rooted apple stocks. Additionally, the apple auxin response factor MdARF19 influences the expression of those auxin efflux carriers and the establishment of the GSA of adventitious roots of apple in response to gravity by directly activating the expression of MdFLP .ConclusionOur findings provide new insights into the transcriptional regulation of MdFLP by the auxin response factor MdARF19 in the regulation of the GSA of adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks in response to gravity."}, {"tab": "tab_2", "article_id": "72587400", "url": "http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12870-019-1847-2&quot;, "reference": "Reference: (2019-05-30). Transcriptional regulation of MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 by MdFLP during apple self-rooted stock adventitious root gravitropism, Available at: http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12870-019-1847-2 Last Accessed: [03-06-19]", "notes": "", "title": "Transcriptional regulation of MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 by MdFLP during apple self-rooted stock adventitious root gravitropism", "body": "AbstractBackgroundThe close planting of dwarfing self-rooted rootstocks is currently a widely used method for apple production; however, self-rooted rootstocks are weak with shallow roots and poor grounding. Therefore, understanding the molecular mechanisms that establish the gravitropic set-point angles (GSAs) of the adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks is important for developing self-rooted apple rootstock cultivars with deep roots.ResultsWe report that the apple FOUR LIPS (MdFLP), an R2R3-MYB transcription factor (TF), functions in establishing the GSA of the adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks in response to gravity. Biochemical analyses demonstrate that MdFLP directly binds to the promoters of two auxin efflux carriers, MdPIN3 and MdPIN10 , that are involved in auxin transport, activates their transcriptional expression, and thereby promotes the development of adventitious roots in self-rooted apple stocks. Additionally, the apple auxin response factor MdARF19 influences the expression of those auxin efflux carriers and the establishment of the GSA of adventitious roots of apple in response to gravity by directly activating the expression of MdFLP .ConclusionOur findings provide new insights into the transcriptional regulation of MdFLP by the auxin response factor MdARF19 in the regulation of the GSA of adventitious roots of self-rooted apple stocks in response to gravity."}]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Assuming that the line `var parsed = JSON.parse(tab_data);` is throwing the error, please add the following code before you call parse. `console.log(typeof tab_data);`. What do you get in the console? (object or string)

Comment: I am getting string not object

Comment: If the JSON string is the text you have posted above, it looks like it contains `&quot` instead of `"`. This make it broken from JSON parsing perspective. Example: `"url": "http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12870-019-1847-2&quot;`

Comment: And how do I stop it from changing to &quot ?

Comment: All quotes appear as &quote however when I pasted into stackoverflow it changed to ". On localhost this problem doesnt happen

Comment: OK. I can see 2 `$.get` in the code. Which one throws the error?

Comment: Both throw the error

Comment: Can you do the HTTP GET you are currently doing from the js code from another platform like postman and see what you get back.